# Remainder of division in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, division

```
a,  b = map(int, input().split())
if (b > 0):
    print(a % b)
else:
    print(a % b + abs(b))
```

Input is a and b, -10^18 <= a,b <= 10^18. b isn't equal to 0. Code must return remainder of division(a/b).
But it is not working correctly.
a and b can be negative also...

Comment: What do you mean by not working? What un-expected output did you get with an input? It *works* fine for me

Comment: acmp.ru Question number 1479. It returned WRONG ANSWER

Comment: acmp.ru Question number 1479 ???? What am I supposed to make of that. [edit] your question to include all the information. Tell me the input, and what answer you expect from it

Comment: Input will be a and b. I must return remainder of division(a / b). 
-10^18 <= a,b <= 10^18. b isn't equal to 0.

Comment: okay what is it equal to then?

Answer (score 1):

In the `else` part, if the remainder is zero, you should not add `abs(b)`.

```
remainder = a % b
print(remainder if remainder >= 0 else remainder + abs(b))
```